# Can I get into freelance web development with just basic web dev knowledge?

Tags: freelance-websites, web-development, webmasters

I'm not an experienced web developer but I'm in college and really needed a quick job as I'm in a financial pit. I can hack up a website in Python/Django in short time depending on complexity. (Eg. a shopping site, simple web apps, etc)

Here is a simple example of my work. [Web Application](https://reelbugs.com) It's a very basic web application. But is there a market for simple web apps in freelancing? Is it possible for me to get into freelancing right away, or am I being too naive?

Answer (score 1):

It's not going to be something you'll see money from in a week... or two... or three... or more.

You have to *find clients*
You have to discuss scope and needs
You have to negotiate contracts
You *might* get a deposit after the above
You have to do the work
You have to make changes
You have to test the work
You have to make changes
You have to test the work
You have to make changes
You have to test the work
You have to submit an invoice
You have to wait for payment to arrive.

It's not an "overnight" income generator until you are well established, and even then few companies pay you immediately. Usually you can do things like Net 15, but most companies use Net 30. (30 days to pay you after completion).

As for "can you".... sure. There are all sorts of clients looking for all sorts of work. How well your particular skill set fairs no one can say.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to offer the basics such as responsive design, or things like a contact form. Granted not all clients want or care about this, but you might want to brush up on these skills if you dont know them. The last thing you want to do is find a client, find their needs, and realise you cant meet them.